# Pre-populate an object with fake data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, faker

Is there a way to pre-populate an object with fake data with Faker without specifying property rules explicitly. I found it is taking way too much time specifying rules for each property in order to populate an object with random data. How about a method that would automatically do that for me, based on property data type. It is so easy to achieve that with NBuilder, unfortunately not supporting .Net Core.

Here is the code I am using to populate CategoryViewModel:

```
var category = PopulateCategoryViewModelFaker().Generate();

    private Faker<CategoryViewModel> PopulateCategoryViewModelFaker()
    {
        var faker = new Faker<CategoryViewModel>();
        //faker.StrictMode(true);
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.DateCreated, f => DateTime.Now);
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.Description, f => f.Lorem.Sentence(2));
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.ParentCategory, f => null);
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.Status, f => null);
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.Title, f => f.Lorem.Sentence(2));
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.CategoryId, f => Guid.NewGuid());
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.CreatedByUser, f => null);
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.CrumbPath, f => null);
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.StatusId, _ctx.CategoryStatuses.First().StatusId);
        faker.RuleFor(x => x.CreatedByUserId, x => Guid.NewGuid());

        return faker;
    }
```

I would be looking something like:

```
        var cat = new CategoryViewModel();
        cat  = new Faker<CategoryViewModel>().Generate();
```

The above creates an object, however with no fake data.

Comment: `NBuilder`, FTW.

Comment: NBuilder is great, awesome choice, but it does not support .Net Core. I am looking for a tool that does the exact same job as NBuilder, but for .Net Core

Comment: There's an issue for porting NBuilder to .NET Core in its repo on GitHub [here](https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder/issues/55).

Comment: Looks as if NBuilder now also supports .NET Core: the [issue](https://github.com/nbuilder/nbuilder/issues/55) mentioned by @MarianDolinský seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

After a little bit of digging, I have found an excellent library that is compatible with .Net Core, and can be used to generate random realistic test data in a very efficient way, without specifying explicitly rules for class properties. In case anyone would look for a substitution for NBuilder library that worked excellent in standard .Net, [GenFu](https://github.com/MisterJames/GenFu) library might be an answer for you for your .Net Core Unit/Integration tests.